# Template naming /style questions

Tags: theming, entities

Good Morning,

I'm using a custom template for an area where members are logged in.  I would like to have a specific template for all pages of the Member content type. I've been able to do this with a page template a la page--node--11.tpl but I don't seem to be able to change the node template to include all the details of the page template (a la the side bars)

Any suggestions for how I can do this with a content type template.  I have custom configs for the sidebars and footers for this content type so I'd like to be able to use a general template and not one for each node.

Answer (score 0):

You can have node type specific page templates by adding custom template name suggestions from the template preprocessor then using those template file names.

For more information see [Page templates depending on node type](https://drupal.org/node/249726).